# CSS Line-height of paragraph too high

Tags: html, css, height, flexbox

I'm having troubles with the height of a paragraph which contains a span element:

[image]

Here is the setup for HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div id="captionRegion" class="captionRegion" 
     style="left: 10%; top: 10%; width: 80%; height: 80%; 
            align-items: flex-end; background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">
       <div class="paragraph" style="justify-content: center; text-align: center; 
                   background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); line-height: initial;">
          <div class="innerContainer">
              <span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 38.4px; 
                           font-family: monospace; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                One line Subtitle.
              </span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
width:160vh; /* 16:9 */
height:90vh; /* 16:9 */
position: absolute;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
font-size: 6vh;
}

.captionRegion{
position: absolute;
z-index: 2147483647;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
}

.paragraph{
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}
```

I am using flex boxes.
Any idea how to make the red paragraph fit to the span line-height size?
Thanks.

Comment: Its showing properly http://jsfiddle.net/6fpzkjv4/

Comment: You can set height to paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Span is an inline element. It has no width or height.

You could turn it into a block-level element, then it will accept your dimension directives.

Use the following style for `span`:

```
display: block;
height:100%;
```

See the working plunkr : "http://plnkr.co/edit/MrCVzIbpETzYEs0N5rV6?p=preview"

Comment: It works, however if I have multiple lines, it won't render well as it increase space between the lines.

Comment: "http://plnkr.co/edit/QA0OpS1YUDWZUqVcnU6Z?p=preview" See this plunkr, if I have two spans instead of 1, then also it looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want the block design, I need the background-color to stick only to the text, not to the block... sorry!

Comment: Background color is for the text which is in span only, there is no other element involved, if you can't use block elements then you cannot set height.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-height on the red container and put it low like: min-height: 5px;

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as the font-size / line-height can dynamically change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to target your browser engine...
becuse I copied the code I tried it on IE it works fine.

Which browser you are using?

If you are using chrome you ahve to use -webkit- or for mozilla -moz-

You can take help of this link [here---](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

[image]

Comment: it is working for you just because your page height is too small

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fpzkjv4/1/

```
span
{
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, the container set with a font-size 6vh was messing with the line-height.

Thanks for the help though.